# AmbiguousMatchException in net8 Blazor web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

I am encountering an AmbiguousMatchException error in my client-side Blazor web app. The error message says "The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: Fallback {*path:nonfile}". I tried to add app.razor containing this lines

```
 <body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

to fix it, but it did not work. I also added builder.RootComponents.Add("#app"); to program.cs but still couldn't solve it. Can anyone help me solve this issue? Here is the page I am trying to call:

```
@page "/add-Product"
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <EditForm Model="MyProduct" Enhance OnInvalidSubmit="HandleSaveProduct" >
                <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
                <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
               <div class="card">
                   <div class="card-header">Add Product</div>
                   <div class="card-body">

                   </div>
                   <div class="card-footer">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i>Save</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </EditForm>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 @code {
    Product MyProduct = new();
    public void HandleSaveProduct()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have conflicting routes in your application. Which path are you using to access the page? You must at least have two pages which match that route, therefore Blazor does not know which one to display and this error occurs.

Comment: hi @Mushroomator this is the url https://localhost:7138/add-Product

Comment: When i moved this code to ecommerce .server it works but when i put it in ecommerce.client I got the previous error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is to add this to   program.cs

```
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(AddUpdateProduct).Assembly);
```

AddUpdateProduct is the name of the component in the client side